# Decode token JWT in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jwt

I am trying to get the uncoded token from a ws, but I do not succeed. The token is JWT. The token that the ws returns to me is the following:

```
{\"token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJDb2RpZ28iOiIxMTY4IiwiVXN1YXJpbyI6IjU0MDMyIiwiUGFzc3dvcmQiOiJmZGM3OTZlNzkwMjk2NTdjZGE2YjY1OWQ3NjI0MjAyYSIsIk5vbWJyZXMiOiJEYW5pbG8gRXN0dWFyZG8iLCJBcGVsbGlkb3MiOiJJdHplcCBMdW5hIiwiTm9tYnJlQ29tcGxldG8iOiJEYW5pbG8gRXN0dWFyZG8gSXR6ZXAgTHVuYSIsIlRva2VuIjoiNzQ1QzMzNjktMUUwMy00QTJBLTk1Q0YtMzI4NTZGRUU0MEQ2Iiwic3RhdHVzIjoiT0siLCJuYmYiOjE1NDE0NDkzOTcsImV4cCI6MTU0MTQ1MTE5NywiaWF0IjoxNTQxNDQ5Mzk3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ5OTc1LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDk5NzUvIn0.aZA9yOosJzQqZdpMkYtzIHOj3oqYv5tU_qffVyIXOkg\"}
```

I only need the following code, without diagonals:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJDb2RpZ28iOiIxMTY4IiwiVXN1YXJpbyI6IjU0MDMyIiwiUGFzc3dvcmQiOiJmZGM3OTZlNzkwMjk2NTdjZGE2YjY1OWQ3NjI0MjAyYSIsIk5vbWJyZXMiOiJEYW5pbG8gRXN0dWFyZG8iLCJBcGVsbGlkb3MiOiJJdHplcCBMdW5hIiwiTm9tYnJlQ29tcGxldG8iOiJEYW5pbG8gRXN0dWFyZG8gSXR6ZXAgTHVuYSIsIlRva2VuIjoiNzQ1QzMzNjktMUUwMy00QTJBLTk1Q0YtMzI4NTZGRUU0MEQ2Iiwic3RhdHVzIjoiT0siLCJuYmYiOjE1NDE0NDkzOTcsImV4cCI6MTU0MTQ1MTE5NywiaWF0IjoxNTQxNDQ5Mzk3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ5OTc1LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDk5NzUvIn0.aZA9yOosJzQqZdpMkYtzIHOj3oqYv5tU_qffVyIXOkg
```

This is the function that the token obtains:

```
this.webService.doLogin(body)
    .then((response) => {
      this.jsonToken = jwt_decode(response.data);
      this.nativeStorage.set("json", this.jsonToken );
      this.toasNative.show(JSON.parse(this.jsonToken) , "3000", "bottom").subscribe();   
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.toasNative.show(error, "3000", "bottom").subscribe();
    });
```

I'm using the library `import * as jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";`

if the token I save it with JSON.stringify () the result is that it adds inverse diagonals to the code.

```
this.jsonToken = JSON.stringify(response.data);
this.nativeStorage.set("json", this.jsonToken);
this.toasNative.show(this.jsonToken, "3000", "bottom").subscribe();

"\"{\\\"token\\\":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJDb2RpZ28iOiIxMTY4IiwiVXN1YXJpbyI6IjU0MDMyIiwiUGFzc3dvcmQiOiJmZGM3OTZlNzkwMjk2NTdjZGE2YjY1OWQ3NjI0MjAyYSIsIk5vbWJyZXMiOiJEYW5pbG8gRXN0dWFyZG8iLCJBcGVsbGlkb3MiOiJJdHplcCBMdW5hIiwiTm9tYnJlQ29tcGxldG8iOiJEYW5pbG8gRXN0dWFyZG8gSXR6ZXAgTHVuYSIsIlRva2VuIjoiNzQ1QzMzNjktMUUwMy00QTJBLTk1Q0YtMzI4NTZGRUU0MEQ2Iiwic3RhdHVzIjoiT0siLCJuYmYiOjE1NDE0NDkzOTcsImV4cCI6MTU0MTQ1MTE5NywiaWF0IjoxNTQxNDQ5Mzk3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ5OTc1LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDk5NzUvIn0.aZA9yOosJzQqZdpMkYtzIHOj3oqYv5tU_qffVyIXOkg\\\"}\"
```

Also try this way, but it returns the decoded token:

```
this.jsonToken = jwt_decode(response.data);
this.toasNative.show(JSON.stringify(this.jsonToken) , "3000", "bottom").subscribe();

{
  "Codigo": "1168",
  "Usuario": "54032",
  "Password": "fdc796e79029657cda6b659d7624202a",
  "Token": "745C3369-1E03-4A2A-95CF-32856FEE40D6",
  "status": "OK",
  "nbf": 1541449397,
  "exp": 1541451197,
  "iat": 1541449397,
  "iss": "http://localhost:49975/",
  "aud": "http://localhost:49975/"
}
```

Also try this way, but it returns `SyntaxError Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

```
 this.jsonToken = jwt_decode(response.data);
      this.nativeStorage.set("json", this.jsonToken );
      this.toasNative.show(JSON.parse(this.jsonToken) , "3000", "bottom").subscribe();
```

**Update**. This is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';  
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { ServiceProvider } from '../../providers/service/service';

import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';
import * as jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  paginaprincipal: any = HomePage;
  loading: any;
  jsonToken: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private webService: ServiceProvider,
    private nativeStorage: Storage,
    private toasNative: Toast) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  doLogin() {
    const body = {
      Codigo: "1168",
      Usuario: "54032",
      Password: "01992004"
    };

    this.webService.doLogin(body)
    .then((response) => {
      //this.jsonToken = jwt_decode(response.data);
      var parse = JSON.parse(response.data);
      this.nativeStorage.set("json", parse);
      this.toasNative.show("Response with JSON.parse() :" + parse, "3000", "bottom").subscribe();   
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.toasNative.show(error, "3000", "bottom").subscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

If you can help me get the token, thank you very much.

Comment: Don't pass the whole object, just the string starting with `eyJhb` etc, i.e. `response.data.token`

Comment: Hi @user184994 I tried with  this.jsonToken = jwt_decode(response.data.token); and the result is InvalidTokenError; invalid token specified

Comment: Make sure that `response.data` is an object. If not, you may need to `JSON.parse` it first.

Comment: Hi @user184994 
I added my code in the question. Could you help me by indicating how I should do it, please? Since I have tried without achieving it. Thank you,

Comment: Seeing as I don't have access to your API, I'd need more information. Can you please `console.log(response.data)`, and let me know exactly what is printed?

Comment: The response.data is : {\"token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJDb2RpZ28iOiIxMTY4IiwiVXN1YXJpbyI6IjU0MDMyIiwiUGFzc3dvcmQiOiJmZGM3OTZlNzkwMjk2NTdjZGE2YjY1OWQ3NjI0MjAyYSIsIk5vbWJyZXMiOiJEYW5pbG8gRXN0dWFyZG8iLCJBcGVsbGlkb3MiOiJJdHplcCBMdW5hIiwiTm9tYnJlQ29tcGxldG8iOiJEYW5pbG8gRXN0dWFyZG8gSXR6ZXAgTHVuYSIsIlRva2VuIjoiNzQ1QzMzNjktMUUwMy00QTJBLTk1Q0YtMzI4NTZGRUU0MEQ2Iiwic3RhdHVzIjoiT0siLCJuYmYiOjE1NDE0NDkzOTcsImV4cCI6MTU0MTQ1MTE5NywiaWF0IjoxNTQxNDQ5Mzk3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ5OTc1LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDk5NzUvIn0.aZA9yOosJzQqZdpMkYtzIHOj3oqYv5tU_qffVyIXOkg\"}

Comment: And what about if you log `JSON.parse(response.data).token`?

Comment: The result is "Undefined"

Comment: Then I have no idea I'm afraid... If `response.data` gives you the string above, I would've expected to be able to use `JSON.parse(response.data)` to access the `token` property

Comment: What do you get for `console.log(typeof JSON.parse(response.data))`?

Comment: The result is: "string"

Comment: It's possible that it's double encoded then... You can try `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data)).token`

Comment: Excelent @user184994 If it was double coded. 
Decoding works. You can add the answer to select it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data is double encoded.

A quick fix would be to double decode it, i.e.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data)).token
```

However, I'd recommend taking a look at your backend it figure out why it's being double encoded in the first place.